# Disable Button using data from database

Tags: sql, javafx

hello I am Trying to disabled a button, the login is Ok, and the button is Disabled when the user access, the Scene Changes, that's ok, but the button is Disabled with or without permissions.

this is the code in the AdminScreenController:

```
  public void  permisos () {
            Integer a=null;
            String b;
            int p1=1;
            int p2=0;

            String Bd="jdbc:sqlserver://THUMANO2:1433;databaseName=QUORA";
            String Usuario="sa";
            String Pass="milkas87";

            String SqlQuery= "SELECT PERMISOS FROM USUARIOS WHERE PERMISOS=? or PERMISOS=? ";
            Connection Conexion = null;

            try {

                Conexion=DriverManager.getConnection(Bd, Usuario, Pass);
                PreparedStatement ps =Conexion.prepareStatement(SqlQuery);
                ps.setInt(1, p1);
                ps.setInt(2, p2);
                ResultSet rs = ps.executeQuery();
                while(rs.next()) {
                b= rs.getString("PERMISOS");
                a=Integer.parseInt(b) ;
                 if(1==a) {
                     btn1.setDisable(false);
                     System.out.println("uno");
                 }
                 else {
                     btn1.setDisable(true);
                     System.out.println("cero");
                 }

                }       
                rs.close();
            }catch(SQLException e){
                JOptionPane.showMessageDialog(null,"error","ERROR",0);
            }
        }

        @Override
        public void initialize(URL location, ResourceBundle resources) {
            permisos();

        }
```

this is the data in the DB:

[image]

Comment: Side note: You may not want to put your server name, sa login & pass out to the public. Have you tried putting a break point on this line `psus=rs.getString("PERMISOS")` to see what the value is for psus?

Comment: [mcve] please ..as has been suggested when you asked the same question a couple of days ago ..

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I made it!

```
---MainController---
----rest of the code---
----While loop-----
if(!usuarioadmin.equals(fusuario.getText().toString())&&pass.equals(fcontrasena.getText().toString().trim())&&usus.equals(fusuario.getText().toString())  ) {


                 try {
                        Stage administrador=new Stage();
                        FXMLLoader carga = new FXMLLoader(getClass().getResource("Admin.fxml"));
                        Parent StackPane =(Parent) carga.load();
                        AdminScreenController controller = carga.<AdminScreenController>getController();
                        controller.deshabilitaboton();
                        Scene scene = new Scene(StackPane);
                        scene.getStylesheets().add(getClass().getResource("application.css").toExternalForm());
                        administrador.setScene(scene);
                        administrador.setTitle("AdminScreen");
                        Stage login=(Stage)fusuario.getScene().getWindow();
                        login.hide();
                        administrador.show();


                 }catch(Exception e) {
                     Logger.getLogger(Application.class.getName()).log(Level.SEVERE, null, e);
                 }
             }

----ScreenAdminController----



@FXML
    private Button btn1;

    public void deshabilitaboton() {
        btn1.setOnMouseEntered(e->{
            btn1.setDisable(true);

        });

    }
```